# How to validate select elements using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, select, angularjs-validation

I have the following HTML on my page, where I have 2 `select` elements. I want them both to be required. I want the second element `currentModel` to remain disabled until the first one is selected with a value other than `Year`, which is my default value.

```
<select class="form-control  input-xsmall select-inline" data-ng-model="currentYear" >
    <option>Year</option>
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
<select  class="form-control  input-xsmall select-inline" data-ng-model="currentModel">
    <option>Model</option>
    <option ng-repeat="model in models" value="{{model.niceName}}">{{model.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Could somebody help me with how to validate the select elements like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to use is ng-model and  [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) instead of manually creating options via `ng-repeat`. Let angular create options for you.

```
<select class="form-control  input-xsmall select-inline" data-ng-model="currentYear"
          ng-options="year for year in years track by year">
    <option value="">Year</option>
</select>

<select  class="form-control  input-xsmall select-inline" data-ng-model="currentModel" 
   ng-disabled="!currentYear" 
   ng-options ="model.niceName as model.name for model in models track by model.niceName">
    <option value="">Model</option>
</select>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/S7jVYX?p=preview)**

- `ng-options="year for year in years track by year"` follows the syntax `label for value in array`
- `ng-options ="model.niceName as model.name for model in models track by model.niceName"` follows the syntax `select as label for value in array`
- Just set the `ng-model` for both the selects. In case of models since i used `select as` syntax (`model.niceName as model.name`) the `currentModel` will have `niceName` property of the selected item. if you remove `select as` part from the model it will have the respective model object.
- set an ng-disabled on the 2nd select based on value of `currentModel`

*since there is a track by bug with ng-select when dealing with objects we need to go with `as` syntax*

Comment: Thanks a ton PSL, works like a charm :). Just one more thing, I wanted them both to be required fields in a form, and I am not quite able to do it.

Comment: Just realized that when selecting a value for `currentModel`, the default value of that dropdown (i.e. `Model`) does not change.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-disabled="currentYear == -1"` select your default value by doing `$scope.currentYear = -1`
This will make the second select box disabled if the currentYear model value is '-1'

```
<select class="form-control  input-xsmall select-inline" data-ng-model="currentYear" >
    <option value="-1">Year</option>
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
<select  class="form-control  input-xsmall select-inline" data-ng-model="currentModel"
    ng-disabled="currentYear == 'Year'">
    <option>Model</option>
    <option ng-repeat="model in models" value="{{model.niceName}}">{{model.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is Plunkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/LIAqMq4TEz9xOCUGPAUs?p=preview